# Adding previous query string parameter in next page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I don't know the previous page parameters in query string and i want to send that on next page.

I am doing like this but not working:

```
<a href="w4_wchange_states_2.aspx?St=AL" + '<% HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl; %>' id="A_AL">Alabama</a>
```

There are 40  tags which redirect to same page.

Please help me how i can do this.

Answer (score 2):

Use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString()` for the *full* url.

Or, just the query string segement:

```
<a href="w4_wchange_states_2.aspx?St=AL&<% 
    Request.Url.Query.Substring(1, Request.Url.Query.Length - 1);
    %>" id="A_AL">Alabama</a>
```

Comment: i don't need full url, i just want to put what is in query string parameters.

Comment: how can i do it in aspx file. i don't want to add server side code for it.

Comment: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'SubString' and no extension method 'SubString' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)